# 2D Arrays & Matrices - Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have to admit, I'm a little stuck on this equals method. I think I'm pretty close because the first JUnit test that we're given passes but when I make a test for one that should return false, I fail and it returns true. Can I get some assistance on this, please?

```
public class Matrix {

// the dimensions of the matrix
private int numRows;
private int numColumns;

// the internal storage for the matrix elements 
private int data[][];

/**
 * @param d - the raw 2D array containing the initial values for the Matrix.
 */
public Matrix(int d[][])
{
    // d.length is the number of 1D arrays in the 2D array
    numRows = d.length; 
    if(numRows == 0)
        numColumns = 0;
    else
        numColumns = d[0].length; // d[0] is the first 1D array
    
    // create a new matrix to hold the data
    data = new int[numRows][numColumns]; 
    
    // copy the data over
    for(int i=0; i < numRows; i++) 
        for(int j=0; j < numColumns; j++)
            data[i][j] = d[i][j];
}



/**
 * Determines whether this Matrix is equal to another object.
 * @param o - the other object to compare to, which may not be a Matrix
 */
@Override // instruct the compiler that we intend for this method to override the superclass' (Object) version
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    // make sure the Object we're comparing to is a Matrix
    if(!(o instanceof Matrix))
        return false;
    
    // if the above was not true, we know it's safe to treat 'o' as a Matrix
    Matrix m = (Matrix)o;
    
    /*
     * TODO: replace the below return statement with the correct code. 
     *  
     *  Returns true if this Matrix is equal to the input Matrix; returns false otherwise
     */ 
    boolean matches = true;
    
    if(o instanceof Matrix)
        for(int i = 0; i < data[i].length; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < data[j].length; j++)
                if(o[i][j] != m[i][j])
                    matches = false;
    
    return matches;
}
```

Comment: Where are the tests? You are returning `true` if a single member of the matrix matches the other, that doesn't sound right. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Some hints to improve your `equals` method. You are checking `o instanceof Matrix` twice. One time is sufficient. You are assuming that `data` has the same or greater dimensions than the matrix you want to compare to. This could raise an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You are better off to compare the dimensions first. If they don't match, you can return `false`. And the most important:  You are comparing `o` with `m` which are referencing the same array! You supposed to compare `m` with `data` whose dimensions you are using to iterate.

Answer (score 1):

If I were a teacher, these are the things I would point out, step-by-step:

1. This won't compile:  `if(o[i][j] != m[i][j])` Neither `o` nor `m` is an array, and so can't have subscripts.
2. Suppose we make this change:  `if (o.data[i][j] != m.data[i][j])` . Now `o.data[i][j]` won't compile, because `o` is an `Object` type, which has no member named `data`.
3. We could use a class cast like this: `if (((Matrix) o).data[i][j] != m.data[i][j])` . Now, it will compile. But, the code above has this line: `Matrix m = (Matrix)o;` So, `o` and `m` point to the *same object*. As long as that's the case, `((Matrix) o).data[i][j] == m.data[i][j]` will *always be `true`*.
4. To fix the above, we need to use two different instances of `Matrix`. We get one instance from the parameter: `o`. The second one is implicit, but has a name: `this`. So, this is what we want for our comparison: `if(this.data[i][j] != m.data[i][j])`

Here are some other comments, outside the scope of your question. You should be able to copy the segments of code, and put them together for a complete solution for a `.equals`.

In general, it is a good idea to begin `.equals` methods with 3 quick tests, like in the following:

```
@Override
public boolean equals (Object o) {
    if (o == this) return true;
    if (o == null) return false;
    if(!(o instanceof Matrix)) return false;
    
     Matrix m = (Matrix)o;
```

If `this` and `o` refer to the same object, `.equals` should be *guaranteed* to return `true`.  In addition to being a quick test, the second will guard against a `NullPointerException` later on in the code if someone passes a `null` reference. If it passes all three tests, you can use the class cast and proceed.

When overriding `.equals`, it's **strongly** recommended that `hascode ()` be overridden also. So, please think about the following line:

```
    if (m.hashCode() != this.hashCode()) return false;
```

If `.hashcode ()` and `.equals` are properly implemented, two objects returning different hash codes are guaranteed to return `false` for `.equals`. However, two objects returning the same hash code could return either `true` or `false` for `.equals`. So, if the `hascode()` test returns `true`, we keep testing:

```
// two matrices can have different sizes. Comparing the sizes early
// will will guard against throwing 
// an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when the sizes are different

if (    m.numRows    != this.numRows 
     || m.numColumns != this.numColumns) return false;
```

Once you have determined that the contents of the two instances of `Matrix` do not match, you can escape the `for` loops with `break`. It could save time if you are processing large matrices.

```
 boolean matches = true;

 outer: for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
           for(int j = 0; numColumns; j++) {
               if(this.data[i][j] != m.data[i][j]) {
                  matches = false;
                  if (!matches)
                    break outer;
            }
        }            
    }        
return matches;
```

}

Comment: You could replace `matches = false;  if (!matches)  break outer;` with `return false;` , which would require replacing `return matches`; with `return true;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```java
if(o instanceof Matrix)
    for(int i = 0; i < data[i].length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; i < data[j].length; j++)
            if(o[i][j] == m[i][j])
                return true;
```

You're looping over every element in the array and when you found any element that matches with the element in the other array, you're returning `true`. I would create a `boolean` (initially set to `true`) and when I found an element that doesn't match, I would set the `boolean` to `false` and return the `boolean` at the end of the method:

```java
boolean matches = true;

if(o instanceof Matrix)
    for(int i = 0; i < data[i].length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; i < data[j].length; j++)
            if(o[i][j] != m[i][j])
                matches = false;

return matches;
```

Comment: Thanks, @TheNitram21 . That helped a lot! I did have to make an edit to my original code because I forgot to provide stuff that was above the equals method. My new issue is that the line that says, "if(o[i][j] == m[i][j])" the type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Matrix.